# How to display a backbone template in a html <div> which loads the data from xml file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am a very new to Backbone.js just started to learn it. I am implementing backbone in my existing web page. I have created an html div which displays the contents fetched from the xml file. Normally it works fine, but when i started to display it using backbone's template and view , it does not show any data on my page.Note that, have written a jQuery code to read data from xml file and display it in html div.So please help me to sole my problem. Up till now i have done following things:

This is my html present in 'index.html':

```
<!--    start Cloud section-->
    <center>
    <section id="clouds">
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:0px;">
            <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 "style="background:white">
                                                <div id="side">
                                                        <div class="tags">

                                                        </div><!--/tags-->
                                                   </div><!--/side-->


                   </div><!--/col-lg-12-->     
             </div><!--/row-->
        </div><!--/container-->
    </section><!--/Cloudtags-->
    </center>


<!--------- end of cloud tags ----------->
```

(note that i have added all backbone dependancies in my file  i.e.jQuery.js,Backbone.js and unerscore.js)
Following is the template in the same file,in which content should load:

```
<script type="text/template" id="cloudtag_tempalte">
     <center>
            <ul class="cld" ">
            <li   >     <a  class="tag1" id="t1"  href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"></a>  </li> 
            <li  >      <a  class="tag2" id="t2"  href="#"></a>     </li>
            <li  >      <a class="tag3"  id="t3"  href="#"></a>     </li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag2" id="t4"  href="#"></a>      </li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag4" id="t5"  href="#"></a>       </li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag1" id="t6"  href="#"></a>       </li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag1" id="t7"  href="#"></a>      </li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag5"id="t8"  href="#"></a>      </li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag2"id="t9"  href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag1"id="t10" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag3"id="t11" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag4"id="t12" href="#"> </a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag1"id="t13" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag5"id="t14" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag1"id="t15" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag2"id="t16" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag1"id="t17" href="https://www.google.com"></a></li> 
            <li  >      <a  class="tag2" id="t18" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag3"id="t19" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag2"id="t20" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag4"id="t21" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag1"id="t22" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag1"id="t23" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag5"id="t24" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag2"id="t25" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag1"id="t26" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag5"id="t27" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag3"id="t28" href="#"> </a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag1"id="t29" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag3"id="t30" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag1"id="t31" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag4"id="t32" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag1"id="t33" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag5"id="t34" href="#"></a></li>
            <li  >      <a  class="tag2"id="t35" href="#"></a></li>

            </ul><!--/cld-->
     </center>
    </script>
```

Following is the code of Backbone in the same index.html file:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var cld_view=Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){

        },
        render: function(){
            // Compile the template using underscore
            var template = _.template( $("#cloudtag_tempalte").html(), {} );
            // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
            this.$el.html( template );
            alert("in render of cldview");
        }

    });

    var cloudtag=new cld_view({el:$(".tags")});
    cloudtag.render();


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your backbone code in [document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

When you pass an `el` to a view, that element needs to be in the `DOM`. Without `document.ready()` your code is executing before the `DOM` is loaded, and so there is no `.tags` element when you call the following line:

```
var cloudtag=new cld_view({el:$(".tags")});
```

Here is some working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Run this code with the DOM is loaded
  $(function() {
    var cld_view=Backbone.View.extend({
      render: function(){
        console.log("in render of cldview");
        var template = _.template( $("#cloudtag_tempalte").html(), {} );
        this.$el.html( template );        
        return this;
      }
    });

    var cloudtag=new cld_view({el:'.tags'});
    cloudtag.render();

  });
```

Some other changes:

1) You can pass the `el` as `{el:'.tags'}` instead of `{el:$(".tags")}`.

2) I added `return this` to the `render` call. This allows you to chain calls with 
`render` like `cloudtag.render().el`

3) I added text to your `<a>` tags, You won't see them displayed if you don't have any text there.

Here is [working demo](http://jsbin.com/AQUGeTe/1/edit) with the changes.